# QSplitter disable scrollbar on resizing QLabel

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have added 2 `QScrollArea`-> `QLabel` in `QSplitter`. And am displaying video on both of them. And by default, both of them have same size..

So, when I increase the size of one `QLabel` by adjusting `QSplitter` handle, the video takes new allocated space and scales accordingly. However, if I then decrease the size of `QLabel`, the video would still show up at previous bigger scale and scrollbars would appear.

I instead want to display video without scrollbars and with whatever scale factor that fits current size.

How can this be achieved?

Here is screenshot of my `dialog.ui`:

[image: This image]

And this is my code for displaying image on `QLabel`

```
multiews[0] = ui->QImageLabel_view0;
multiews[1] = ui->QImageLabel_view1;

multiews[image_view]->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qImg).scaled(multiews[image_view]->width(),multiews[image_view]->height(),Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
```

**Update:**

I tried to manage desired behaviour by managing

```
void Dialog::on_splitter_2_splitterMoved(int pos, int index)
{
    if(m_videos[0].video_playing){
    int w= ui->scrollArea_2->width();
    int h=ui->scrollArea_2->height();
    ui->QImageLabel_view0->setFixedSize(w-20,h-20);
    }
    if(m_videos[1].video_playing){
    int w= ui->scrollArea_1->width();
    int h=ui->scrollArea_1->height();
    ui->QImageLabel_view1->setFixedSize(w-20,h-20);
    }
}
```

And am setting back policy to expanding when am using zoom out/zoom in.

```
void Dialog::PausePlayingVideo()
{    ...
     m_scrollarea[active_view]->setWidgetResizable(true);
     multiews[active_view]->setMaximumSize(10000,10000);
     m_scrollarea[active_view]->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
     multiews[active_view]->adjustSize();
     multiews[active_view]->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding,QSizePolicy::Expanding);
}
```

However, the qLabel size is not expanding with this code. Does anybody know, what am doing wrong?

Comment: can you share your code as well?

Comment: Why are you using scroll area if you don't want scroll bars?

Comment: I am using scrollarea for zoomout/zoomin functions. However, in general I would like to display video that fits the content.

Comment: Does anybody know answer ??